# UITableview dynamic number of columns

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell, multiple-columns

I am developing an iPad app, a part of which is a tableview with multiple columns. I am already using custom cells for displaying multiple columns(a label for each column), but my problem now is the app will be getting a web service response, based on which the number of columns will vary. Is there any way I can dynamically change the custom cell components, i.e. based on the response add or remove the labels from the custom cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these lines of code will help you

```
int x = 5;
for(NSString *yourString in yourArrayOfStrings)
{
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 5, 75,50)];
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(titleLabel.frame.size.width, 999);
    CGSize myStringSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:titleLabel.font 
                                        constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;    // for multiple lines 
    CGRect lblFrame = titleLabel.frame;
    lblFrame.size.height = myStringSize.height;
    x = myStringSize.width + 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Here are you adding labels directly to UITableviewcell instead of using a custom cell? Coming to think of that, yes that seems easier and possible. But do you foresee any issues or problems with this approach in the long run?